# Array sum for certain keys in while loop

Tags: php

Tried finding a solution on SO and I found multiple questions that are similar but none of them were limited to a number of keys.

I am building a questionaire that has an algorithm based on which it recommends you three winners out of 7 based on the points that they got on each question answer. The table has 10 columns: id, question_no, answer and 7 that are holding the point values.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";

$question = array();
$question[1] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_01']);
// the rest of the questions go here
$question[10] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_10']);

    $i = 0;
    $array_sum=[];
     while ($i < 10){
      $i++;     
       $sql =  "SELECT * FROM partners WHERE question_no = $i AND answer = '".$question[$i]."'";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

       $final_array_1 = array();

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
      {

        $final_array_1 = $row;
            $array_sum = array_map(function () {
                return array_sum(func_get_args());
            }, $array_sum, $final_array_1);
       print_r($final_array_1);
       echo "<br/>";
      }
}
```

The output of this would be something like:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => A [3] => 5 [4] => 5 [5] => 5 [6] => 5 [7] => 5 [8] => 5 [9] => 5 )

Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 2 [2] => B [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => 8 [7] => 8 [8] => 0 [9] => 0 )
```

And so on for the other 8 arrays.

Basically now I need to add up the values of all the keys from 3 to 9 but since I got these values in a "while" I'm not really sure how to achieve this.

I also need to keep those individual arrays that I get so I can store the options that the user selected in the form in the database.

Let me know if you need any additional details.

Comment: loop through the array from 3 to 9 and increment another variable with the value of each key?

Comment: @ADyson Yes. That's the idea.

Comment: so...you know how to make a for loop? After that it's trivial.

Comment: I know the theoretical side, haven't used them that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to loop through your arrays from indexes 3 to 9 and sum the values of each index.

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$question = array();
$question[1] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_01']);
// the rest of the questions go here
$question[10] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['question_10']);
$i = 0;

$sums = array(); //this will hold the sums of all the various indexes
while ($i < 10)
{
  $i++;     
  $sql =  "SELECT * FROM partners WHERE question_no = $i AND answer = '".$question[$i]."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
  {
    for ($count = 3; $count <= 9; $count++) {
      if (!isset($sums[$count]) $sums[$count] = 0;
      $sums[$count] += $row[$count];
    }
  }
}
var_dump($sums); //just for debugging, to show you the totals
?>
```

Comment: And I add this in the final "while"?

Comment: Assuming you want to sum each of the rows in your database, yes

Comment: Ah, I think I didn't explained correctly. You're adding the values in the same array. What I meant was adding the values from the next iteration over the original ones. Like if I have an array that has the values (1 , 3) and on the next iteration it's (5 , 2) the sum should be (6, 5) not 4.

Comment: ok I see. I've updated the question with what I think should work. You'll get an array where index 3 contains the sum of all the index 3s in your database. Same for index 4, etc, up to 9.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work as intended. Basically what I need to do is add the "for" part in the while right?

Comment: yes. and define the "sums" array outside the loop. What result do you get from this? I've just realised the var_dump should be after the end of the loop, modified the answer

Comment: Something like this: array(7) { [3]=> int(7) [4]=> int(7) [5]=> int(8) [6]=> int(7) [7]=> int(10) [8]=> int(10) [9]=> int(9) }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135599/discussion-between-sporedev-and-adyson).